# Pentaho Error - ConnectionServiceImpl.ERROR_0009 - Connection to database [null] failed

Tags: mysql, database, pentaho, data-warehouse, mysql-connector

I'm trying to setup pentaho connection with MySQL server(localhost). However, this error **"ConnectionServiceImpl.ERROR_0009 - Connection to database [null] failed"** appears when i try testing the connection. The information about server should be right. 
Information Picture:
[image: Information Picture]

[i've no password for root account in MySQL] and MySQL connector file have been insered in the pentaho server lib folder.

Connector Folder Picture:
[image: Connector Folder Picture]

I've looked for log file and i found this about my connection test:

```
2017-07-08 17:12:02,915 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.ConnectionServiceImpl] Error Start: Pentaho pentaho-platform-core 7.1.0.0-12
2017-07-08 17:12:02,915 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.ConnectionServiceImpl] ::: Can't get connection from Pool
org.pentaho.platform.api.data.DBDatasourceServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: PooledDatasourceHelper.ERROR_0009 - Unable to pool Data Source [ Data_Warehouse_Incidenti ]. Cannot initialize org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver.
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.PooledDatasourceHelper.setupPooledDataSource(PooledDatasourceHelper.java:319)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.connections.sql.SQLConnection.initDataSource(SQLConnection.java:581)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.connections.sql.SQLConnection.connect(SQLConnection.java:597)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.connections.sql.SQLConnection.setProperties(SQLConnection.java:108)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.PentahoConnectionFactory.getConnection(PentahoConnectionFactory.java:124)
    at org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.ConnectionServiceImpl.testConnection(ConnectionServiceImpl.java:323)
    at org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.ConnectionService.testConnection(ConnectionService.java:240)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor367.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.JAXRSPluginServlet.service(JAXRSPluginServlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.JAXRSPluginServlet.service(JAXRSPluginServlet.java:117)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.PluginDispatchServlet.service(PluginDispatchServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoWebContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoWebContextFilter.java:195)
    at com.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoEnterpriseWebContextFilter.doFilter(SourceFile:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoRequestContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoRequestContextFilter.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:191)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.PentahoBasicProcessingFilter.doFilterInternal(PentahoBasicProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.HttpSessionPentahoSessionIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionPentahoSessionIntegrationFilter.java:271)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.pentaho.ui.servlet.SystemStatusFilter.doFilter(SourceFile:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.WebappRootForwardingFilter.doFilter(WebappRootForwardingFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoPathDecodingFilter.doFilter(PentahoPathDecodingFilter.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2510)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: PooledDatasourceHelper.ERROR_0009 - Unable to pool Data Source [ Data_Warehouse_Incidenti ]. Cannot initialize org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver.
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.PooledDatasourceHelper.setupPooledDataSource(PooledDatasourceHelper.java:167)
    ... 96 more
2017-07-08 17:12:02,917 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.ConnectionServiceImpl] Error end:
```

I've looked for many solution but I haven't found anything. What's missing about it?

Comment: It seams to be the most popular question when you goolge Error_0009. 
- Why don't you use the MySQL Database type ?
- And if you need the generic database connection, check your Driver.class. The mysql-conector-java contains two drivers: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver and  org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver. Help Kettle by providing a hint.

Comment: Cause MySQL database type doesn't appear in my list. I've followed all the procedures to install it with no results. I've also tried to do it from prompt but nothing happends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue, I resolved copying mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar in

- tomcat/lib
- schema-workbench/lib
- schema-workbench/drivers
- pentaho-server/data/lib (not sure it was useful)
- in a folder called 'jdbc' under folders inside pentaho folder (I used the search function of the filesystem)

I've stop the server and restart the server.

In this way the option "Mysql" appeared in Database Type in the photo up.

Finally I used org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver for the field Driver Class Name.

Answer (score 0):

There a few things here:

- Is your MySQL server running on `localhost`? Is it running on port `3306`?
- Are you sure this is the correct connection you are showing? In the log it says `Cannot initialize org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` (the old version), but in the connection window you have provided `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` (the new version). Why the difference=
- This looks to me that you are using the wrong driver class. Is the connection defined elsewhere?

**EDIT**

First result for "pentaho driver jars directory" is [this page](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.3/0D0/160/030). It states that external jars have to go into the directory

```
pentaho/jdbc-distribution
```

Afterwards a file has to be executed

```
distribute-files.bat <name of JDBC driver JAR>
```

Then restart the server. Also, there is a list of folders for the applications you use.

Comment: Yes, my server si running on localhost and the port is 3306. I've tried to instatiate the old and the new version (org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver) but the error is the same. The other tools i used (kettle, schema workbench) don't require to specify the Driver class, i've just to put jar file in the lib folder, so i'm pretty sure the driver works but i don't know how give it to petaho server